# Is there a logarithm identity that simplifies this expression?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I'm left with a tantalizing expression that looks like it could be simplified:

$$
\large{\log_{log_a(m)}(log_a(n))}
$$

Is there a way to eliminate one of the logs in this logjam?

**Alternatively**, that expression is the exponent of a larger expression:

$$
\large{t^{(\log_{log_a(m)}(log_a(n)))} = log_a(n)^{(\log_{log_a(m)}(t))}}
$$

Is there a way to eliminate either one of the logs or the exponentiation?

Answer (score 0):

Use the change of base formula a couple of times
\begin{eqnarray*}
\log_{\log_a m}(\log_a n) = \frac{ \ln \log_a n}{ \ln \log_a m} =\frac{ \ln  \left(\frac{ \ln n}{\ln a}\right) }{ \ln  \left(\frac{ \ln m}{\ln a}\right) } = \frac{ \ln \ln n - \ln \ln a }{ \ln \ln m - \ln \ln a }
\end{eqnarray*}
and this does not look like it will simplify very much from here $ \ddot \frown$